# How do you add two values into a list as one key? C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list

The following code will work, but it will read as key1 and key2 because there are two string values

```
IList<string> myData = new List<string>()
{
     "string1","data2"
};
```

I want to achieve something like this, so I can retrieve any of the two values using index key

```
IList<string> myData = new List<string>()
{
     {"string1","data2"},
     {"example","sample"}
};
```

The reason for this is that I am trying to use the following code:

```
Console.WriteLine(myData[0][1]);
```

^ Where 0 is the actual index key and 1 being 'data2'.

@Edit

I do not want to use dictionary as keys are most likely to be duplicate, sorry for confusion

Comment: What you think you want is either a list of lists, or a two-dimensional array. If you explain what purpose it serves at a higher level of abstraction, there may be a better solution. I can read the line of code you say you want to use, but that's not an explanation of what you're trying to accomplish with it.

Comment: Otherwise known as an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: This sentence is nonsensical: "0 is the actual index key and 1 being 'data2'" Please rephrase it. Are you saying that the line of code should write `"data2"` to the console?

Comment: It sounds like using a List of Tuple<string, string> would be a possible solution, but like above comments have stated, a description of your general problem instead of your attempted solution would allow for a better answer

Comment: @EdPlunkett: It's not _that_ nonsensical (though it could have been more clear) I read the OP's question in a way that every element at index `2k` is the **key** that matches the **value** found at index `2k+1`. In other words: `new List<string>() { "key1", "value1", "key2", "value2", "key3", "value3" }`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that you don't want a dictionary. Now please clarify what you DO want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Tuple<string, string>` [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx), like this:

```
var list = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
list.Add(Tuple.Create("A", "B"));
```

Comment: If I were a betting man, I'd put money on a list of tuples. We'll see if OP ever clarifies.

Comment: Thank you it works, but how can you retrieve only one value? For example, "B"

Comment: Console.WriteLine(myData[0].Item2); does the job, Thank YOU!